# Getting Erreur HTTP 403.4 - Forbidden after configuring IIS 7.0 to use SSL

Tags: http, ssl, iis, https, iis-7

I got the error "Erreur HTTP 403.4 - Forbidden" after configuring IIS to use SSL and that's by running the command line : %windir%\system32\inetsrv>AppCmd set config "Default Web Site" -commitPath:APPHOST -section:access -sslFlags:Ssl

The https navigation works fine with me, but when I want to launch a web site using http It shows me the error "Erreur HTTP 403.4 - Forbidden".

How can I allow http connection from my IIS ?

Answer (score 0):

Check in IIS "SSL settings" you may have "REQUIRE" enabled.

You can also set up a Rewrite rule to enforce HTTPS this way if you use http it will redirect to HTTPS. check [this link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dawiese/2016/06/07/redirect-from-http-to-https-using-the-iis-url-rewrite-module/).

I am assuming you access the same site.

If this happens in different sites you might need to use SNI and define hostnames with bindings.

Comment: The problem is not in making https working but in disabling enforcing all my web sites to be launched by https instead oh http. Cauz the command that I used was to configure a site to accept only server HTTPS connections. So when using http I got the error. And now I'm looking for a way to disable the SSL connections only.

Comment: Read the first line of my answer.

Comment: I did check but I don't have the REQUIRE enabled in my SSL settings

Comment: Do you have a binding on port 80 for this site?

Comment: I newly added an http certficate on port 80 on IIS and browsed using http and the error is showen

Comment: do not add certificate on port 80 if what you want is an HTTP connection. There is no such thing as HTTP certificate afaik.

Comment: You only need 2 bindings, one on port 80 withouth any certificate (HTTP) and one for port 443 with a certificate (HTTPS)

Comment: I add It because on my IIS browsing web site using http *80 was not shown anymore so I was obliged to add it so that  I can browse using http